# Issue loading sector from hard disk

Tags: assembly, nasm, intel, x86-16, bootloader

I have wrote an MBR boot loader and it detects the partitions but fails to load them. Interrupt 13 is failing, does anyone know what I am doing wrong, I am sure its something silly been trying to fix it for hours now

My bootloader code is:

```
[BITS 16]   ;tell the assembler that its a 16 bit code
[ORG 0]
%define PARTITION_TABLE_START 0x1be
%define PARTITION_TABLE_END 0x1ee
%define PARTITION_ENTRY_SIZE 16
%define COPY_DEST 0x7e00
_begin:
; We must copy the bootloader into a different area of memory
mov ax, 0
mov ds, ax
_copy:
mov si, 0x7c00+_begin
mov di, COPY_DEST
mov cx, 0
._continue:
lodsb
stosb
cmp cx, 0x200
je ._finish
inc cx  
jmp ._continue
._finish:
jmp 0x7e0:_start
_start:
; We are running at 0x7e00 now
mov ax, 0x7e0
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
mov ss, ax

; Save drive number
mov byte[_drive_no], dl

mov si, _welcome_message
call _print


mov si, _find_message
call _print

mov bx, PARTITION_TABLE_START
_csearch:
cmp byte [bx], 0x80
je _bootable_found
cmp bx, PARTITION_TABLE_END
jae _no_bootable_found
add bx, PARTITION_ENTRY_SIZE
jmp _csearch


_bootable_found:
mov si, _found_message
call _print
; BX Contains current entry position
mov ah, 0x02
mov al, 1
mov dh, [bx+1], ; Head
mov cl, [bx+2] ; Sector
shr cl, 2 ; Ignore bit 6-7 they are not for us
mov ch, [bx+3] ; Cylinder (warning only 8 bits supported)
mov byte dl, [_drive_no] ; Drive number
; Destination: 0x7c00
push ax
mov ax, 0x7c0
mov es, ax
mov bx, 0
pop ax
int 0x13
jc _read_error
mov si, _press_any_key_to_load
call _print
mov ah, 0
int 0x16
; Read success lets jump to the new bootloader
jmp 0x7c0:0

_read_error:
mov si, _read_error_msg
call _print
jmp $

_no_bootable_found:
mov si, _no_partition
call _print
jmp $


_print:
    mov ah, 0x0e
._loop: 
    lodsb
    cmp al, 0
    je ._done
    int 0x10
    jmp ._loop
._done:
    ret
_welcome_message: db 'Welcome to NibbleBits bootloader', 10, 13, 0
_find_message: db 'Will find first active partition', 10, 13, 0
_found_message: db 'Active partition found', 10, 13, 0
_no_partition: db 'No active partition could be found', 10, 13, 0
_read_error_msg: db 'Failed to load partition', 10, 13, 0
_press_any_key_to_load: db 'Press any key to load the partition', 10, 13, 0
_drive_no: db 0

TIMES 510 - ($ - $$) db 0   ;fill the rest of sector with 0
DW 0xAA55           ; add boot signature at the end of bootloader
_end:
```

Comment: Following the forum rules, you should provide the code over here dear.

Comment: You could have simplified the entire LODSB/STOSB by using a `REP MOVSB`. But with that beign said `STOSB` relies on _ES_ being set. You show do a `mov es, ax` along with `mov ds, ax` . That may not be an issue but the first thing that stands out that should be fixed (it may not work on all hardware) but in many virtual environment it is probably already 0.

Comment: I assume you are copying a partition table into the bootloader from elsewhere after you create the MBR from this code?

Comment: Yes Michael I am currently manually entering the partition table in a hex editor I wrote a program to do it for me but it has a few bugs, it was like 5 in the morning when I did it lol probably something simple. Can any of you see my issue. I believe I am setting head, sectors ect correctly. Seek here: http://wiki.osdev.org/Partition_Table

Comment: `shr cl, 2` divides the sector number by 4. You really sure that is what you want? If your intent was to simply zero out bits 6 and 7 maybe you meant `and cl, 0x3f` ? Even better I wouldn't do anything with the values after getting them from the partition table. Read them as is into dh, cl, ch.

Comment: Problem is if I did that then it would be invalid as bit 6 and 7 are for cylinder. I'll change it to bitwise and though :)

Comment: Int 13h/ah=2 understands the top 2 bits of the sector number are for cylinders and it knows that those 2 bits get added to the top of the cylinder to make it a 10-bit value. The CHS numbers from the partition table were designed to be used directly with the CHS related disk routines.

Comment: One thing I read though is that for MBR bit 0 is the leftmost bit and bit 7 is the right mostbit would that be true? If so then wouldnt it be different

Comment: In an 8 bit value the Most Significant bit (7) is on the left and the Least significant bit is on the right (0).

Comment: I thought thaat to just I read something that said differently. Regarding the interrupt 13 understanding top 2 bits of sector number is to make 10 bit value I did not know that Micheal thanks that might be my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my code is fine, did change a few things that Michael Petch proposed but the actual loading was fine. The problem was that when I was using linux's "dd" program to copy the bootsector it was truncating the entire file. I solved this by enabling a flag to prevent truncating.